# WildFly 11 não reconhece driver do MySQL ao fazer deploy

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, wildfly, jta

Configurei o meu projeto Java Web pra usar JTA ao realizar transações com o Banco de Dados. Meu projeto tem 4 módulos do Maven, um é exclusivo para as classes model e para a camada de persistência. Quando compilo no Maven o resultado é sucesso, mas ao tentar subir a aplicação no WildFly, estoura o problema abaixo de configuração do driver MySQL:

```
    Deploying on WildFly Application Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: true
    force redeploy: true
Iniciando WildFly Application Server
WildFly Application Server iniciado
Implantação inicial de for_clinic-web até /usr/local/WildFly/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
Distribuição inicial do for_clinic-web completada
Implantando /usr/local/WildFly/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
{"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
"Services that were unable to start:" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".CdiValidatorFactoryService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener\".WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteBusiness.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteBusiness.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteBusiness.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteDAO.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteDAO.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteDAO.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteService.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteService.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.pacienteService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.usuarioDAO.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.usuarioDAO.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.usuarioDAO.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.usuarioService.START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.usuarioService.WeldInstantiator",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.usuarioService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".deploymentCompleteService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".jndiDependencyService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\".\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\".env.\"br.com.for_systems.for_clinic_domain.persistence.dao.GenericDAO\".entityManager",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war#FOR_Clinic-PU\"",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"for_clinic-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war#FOR_Clinic-PU\".__FIRST_PHASE__",
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./for_clinic",
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./for_clinic.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"
],
"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"]
```

Meu arquivo persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="FOR_Clinic-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>JPA-Hibernate Configuração</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/for_clinic_DS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

E aqui está a configuração do meu DataSource no WildFly:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/for_clinic_DS" pool-name="for_clinic_DS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/for_clinic?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password>310990</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
```

Dentro do diretório do WildFly, configurei e adicionei o driver do MySQL no seguinte caminho (modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main) e adicionei o module.xml abaixo:

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Alguém faz ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?
Obrigado!

Comment: vc pode da mais detalhes ?

Comment: Olá, amigo! Meu projeto está dividido em 4 módulos. Em um apenas eu configurei o JPA com persistence.xml, que é o módulo com as classes modelos e DAOs. Quando executo o maven, faz o build com sucesso, mas ao tentar executar a aplicação acontece aquele erro ali acima.
Que tipo de informação mais pode ser útil eu passar, amigo? 
Obrigado pela força!

Comment: mais na sua IDE funciona ?

Comment: Estou usando o NetBeans e funciona apenas o Maven. Quando tento executar pelo próprio NetBeans, acontece o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, pessoal!
Encontrei a causa desse problema. Excluí meu DataSource no  arquivo de configuração do WildFly e deixei apenas o driver para ver o resultado. Então o console apontou que eu estava usando um pacote deprecated do driver MySQL. O pacote certo para utilizar é este: **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver**

Então a configuração correta do DataSource e do Driver no arquivo **standalone-full.xml** segue abaixo:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/for_clinic_mysql_DS" pool-name="for_clinic_mysql_DS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/for_clinic?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>310990</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

Agora está ocorrendo um outro problema de cast do WildFly 11 com o Dom4J, mas como creio que em nada tem a ver com este, resolvi abrir uma outra pergunta neste link abaixo:

[Erro de cast do WildFly 11 com Dom4J](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275917/erro-de-cast-do-wildfly-11-com-dom4j)

Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar!